# Start dart application from Server and load elements

Tags: dart

I'm new in dart's programming and I'm building a dart app and I would like to start it from the server side. Like loading my homepage when I enter the url of my webpage.

On my server side I have this code that I took from tutorials from dart's webpage:

```
var server;

  try{
    server = await HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.LOOPBACK_IP_V6, 4040);
  }catch(e){
    print("Couldn't bind to port 4044: $e");
    exit(-1);
  }
  await for(HttpRequest req in server){
    var file = new File('index.html');

    if(await file.exists()){
      print("Serving index.html.");
      req.response.headers.contentType = ContentType.HTML;
      try{
        await file.openRead().pipe(req.response);
      }catch(e){
        print("Couldn't read file: $e");
        exit(-1);
      }
    }else{
      print("Couldn't open index.html");
      req.response..statusCode = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND..close();
    }
  }
```

But now my problem is about the client side, my elements are not loading, like css, images, etc.

[You can see the appearance here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FqHa.png)

I think that I need to set something at my server side to load that. What is it?

Comment: I assume what you're serving your Dart server is the resulting output of running `pub build` on a Dart browser application (`build/web/**`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the core `dart:io` methods for serving files is often not the easiest way. Take a look at [`shelf`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shelf), f.e. It's a really neat framework for creating server applications that has a lot of plugins and extensions for middleware etc.

In your case, it seems like you just want to serve static content. I'd suggest you use [`shelf_static`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shelf). It would go like this:

```
import 'package:shelf/shelf_io.dart' as io;
import 'package:shelf_static/shelf_static.dart';

void main() {
  var handler = createStaticHandler('your-web-directory/',
      defaultDocument: 'index.html');

  io.serve(handler, InternetAddress.LOOPBACK_IP_V6, 4040);
}
```